# cannot access XAML element from C# code

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, windows-8.1

I am trying to connect an xaml element to c# code but its not working. Here is the code :

```
<WebView x:Name="twitterView" Height="500"/>
```

This is the code at HubPage.xaml and

```
twitterView.NavigateToString("...");
```

this is the code HubPage.xaml.cs but the error is "the name 'twitterView' does not exist in the current context". What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Just a note: It's perfectly okay (even encouraged) to post an answer to your own question if you figure it out yourself. :)

Comment: @OguzGelal Mark an answer as accepted which solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer by @OguzGelal**

I solved this problem. If anyone is interested, the problem was I was using Hub's and `DataTemplates` along with it. And `DataTemplates` could not be reached directly from the code.

So, you should hook the `Loaded` event of the control and get the it from `sender` parameter.

[Here is the reference](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-hub-control-getting-started-tutorial-semanticzoom/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using an uninitialised variable. You've gave to little code to judge but the error says exactly about this problem. Give us the line where you create the twitterView variable.

Comment: twitterView variable should have been initialized by the initializeComponents() method because it is an xaml element at the page, but it isnt. Thats the problem.